# How to prevent local plugins from loading on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I recently tested my website on mobile and notecied terrible `loading times`. I found out that these fonts were loading but aren't being used on the site itself:

```
wp-content/plugins/boostify-header-footer-builder/assets/fonts/ionicons.ttf
```

```
wp-content/plugins/elementskit-lite/modules/controls/assets/fonts/elementskit.woff?y24e1e
```

in addition to Googles:

```
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2
```

```
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc4.woff2
```

I don't use any of these and they take up almost 0,5 mb. How do I prevent them from loading?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
function remove_fonts_stylesheet() {  
    wp_dequeue_style( 'google-fonts-roboto' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'elementskit' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'litespeedfont' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_fonts_stylesheet', 999 );
```